# Spring - Dynamically create JMSTemplates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms

I am using Spring boot, and I would like to dynamically create multiple JMS Templates, as I would like to connect to different JMS instances. I am aware of the standard approach of using annotations, linking the ConnectionFactory to the JMSTemplate. I would expect a different JMSTemplate to each different JMS Instance.

I have the connection details currently loaded into a Map, I would like to dynamically create a JMSTemplate for each key.

The main purpose is to publish messages to Topic destinations based on a map lookup. But for testing, it would be could to have listeners as well.

Potential approaches:

1) add the JMSTemplates to a map that is associated with a Spring Component, and lookup the JMSTemplate on spring component map.

2) what about dynamically registering multiple jmsTemplate beans using:

BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(JmsTemplate.class);
            CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();

```
         builder.addPropertyValue("connectionFactory", cachingConnectionFactory);      // set property value
        DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        factory.registerBeanDefinition("jmsTemplateName", builder.getBeanDefinition());
```

Then lookup the jms bean -> ctx.getBean("jmsTemplateName");

Which approach is favorable?

Please advise.

B

Comment: Are you planning to poll MQs or you want to dynamically register listeners also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you have `ConnectionFactory` objects in a map, you can create similar map of `JmsTemplate`s. Use this [JmsTempalte contructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#JmsTemplate-javax.jms.ConnectionFactory-) and after one loop (or stream) and you can have map of `JmsTemplate`s. So sending is easy.

Harder part would be listeners. If you have dynamic destinations, you need to forget about listener annotations (`@JmsListener`). You can make it working by creating map of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.

Each container will be created by something like:

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
container.setDestination(topic);
container.setMessageListener(listenerInstance);
container.start();
```

You can also control lifecycle of each listener container via stop, shutdown, ....

But bear in mind that handling a lot of queues this way may be resource intensive. Also you will need to take care about closing resources yourself probably (Spring wouldn't do it for you).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @user518066 did you have any success using this approach?

Comment: I personally didn't ever need this. I just sketched theory how it would be doable. IF you can create single JMS interface this way, I don't see a reason why you can't create more of them