# SpringBoot application publish and read from ActiveMQ topic

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have two receivers that should read from a topic. But only one random receiver gets message like it's actually reading from a queue not a topic. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144561/how-to-listen-to-topic-using-spring-boot-jms) answer but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code.

**Application.java:**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application {
    public static final String MAILBOX_TOPIC = "inbox.topic";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Launch the application
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);

        // Send a message with a POJO - the template reuse the message converter
        System.out.println("Sending an email message.");
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(MAILBOX_TOPIC, new Email("info@example.com", "Hello"));
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                               DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
}
```

**FirstReceiver.java:**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import static hello.Application.MAILBOX_TOPIC;

@Component
public class FirstReceiver {

    @JmsListener(destination = MAILBOX_TOPIC, containerFactory = "topicListenerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(Email email) {
        System.out.println("FirstReceiver <" + email + ">");
    }

}
```

**SecondReceiver.java:**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import static hello.Application.MAILBOX_TOPIC;

@Component
public class SecondReceiver {
    @JmsListener(destination = MAILBOX_TOPIC, containerFactory = "topicListenerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(Email email) {
        System.out.println("SecondReceiver <" + email + ">");
    }

}
```

**Email.java:**

```
package hello;

public class Email {

    private String to;
    private String body;

    public Email() {
    }

    public Email(String to, String body) {
        this.to = to;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Email{to=%s, body=%s}", getTo(), getBody());
    }

}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-messaging-jms</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please assist me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add `spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true` to `application.properties`

**UPDATE:**

you need to change 2 things :

**1.**

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                           DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    // the configurer will use PubSubDomain from application.properties if defined or false if not
    //so setting it on the factory level need to be set after this
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return factory;
}
```

**2.**

```
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend( new ActiveMQTopic(MAILBOX_TOPIC), new Email("info@example.com", "Hello"));
```

or inject this bean

Comment: That looks like a global setting. Why factory.setPubSubDomain(true); doesn't work? What would I do if need to have both topic/queue?