# active-mq artemis springboot clustered topic load balancing (round robin) issue

Tags: publish-subscribe, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

After spending a lot of time in configuring and trying a lot of solutions to make Artemis work in a **cluster** mode like the **local** mode in a ***publish-subscribe*** (topic).

So, I 've prepared 3 *consumers* on different *nodes* and a *producer* that publish messages on only one node. 

I expect that the 3 consumers receives their own copy of messages like described in  [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/clustered/clustered-topic)!

The problem is the cluster (Core Bridge) still round robin messages between the 3 nodes.

---

> My project Github Repo

[spring-boot-artemis-clustered-topic](https://github.com/hosnimed/spring-boot-artemis-clustered-topic)

---

> Broker Cluster Config

```
<!-- Using STRICT is like setting the legacy forward-when-no-consumers 
parameter to true--> 
<!-- Using ON_DEMAND is like setting the legacy forward-when-no-consumers 
parameter to false.-->
<cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
     <address>jms</address>
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
     </cluster-connection>

</cluster-connections>
```

---

> Consumers behavior
>   [artemis-b1-b2-b3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPLWF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ConnectionFactoryClusteredConfig.pubSubFactory()` method, try moving `factory.setPubSubDomain(true)` after `configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory)` as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416121/832268.