# How to use a topic in Red Hat AMQ 7 using AMQP 1.0 and consume in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, amqp, activemq-artemis, amq

How does one configure and use a Topic (publisher - subscriber model) in Red Hat AMQ 7 using AMQP 1.0 and consume in Spring Boot

I have configured the topic as follows in the Red Hat AMQ console

[image: Create multicast Address]

[image: Create multicast queue inside address]

[image: Queue created]

I have created a Spring Boot app

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>amqp-1-topic-producer</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.amqphub.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-10-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

With `application.properties`:

```
amqphub.amqp10jms.remote-url=amqp://localhost:61616
amqphub.amqp10jms.username=admin
amqphub.amqp10jms.password=admin
my.topic.name=mySOQueue
```

Creating a publisher seems to be working

```java
@Component
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);

    @Autowired
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${my.topic.name}")
    public String queueName;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000L)
    public void sendMessages() {
        sendMessage("Hello World topic");
    }

    public void sendMessage(final String payload) {
        LOG.info("============= Sending: " + payload);
        this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, payload);     
  }
}
```

I am not getting any exceptions with the log output

```
============= Sending: Hello World topic Connection ID:9231142a-a196-48bf-987a-1b5d65fc6955:96
connected to server: amqp://localhost:61616
```

I however cannot see the message count go up in the Red Hat AMQ console. It stays at 0.

If I try to create a consumer

```java
@Component
public class Consumer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    @JmsListener(destination = "jms.topic.demoTopic")
    public void processMsg(final String message) {
        LOG.info("Received: " + message);
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
Open of resource:(JmsConsumerInfo: { ID:efcdcfd8-eb5b-4438-b4ec-a8fa2cf8e9cf:1:1:1, destination = jms.topic.demoTopic }) failed: Address jms.topic.demoTopic is not configured for queue support [condition = amqp:illegal-state]
```

I know if I use ApacheMQ I can create an `ActiveMQTopicConnectionFactory` and configure that with a public subscriber model but I have no idea how to do it with the amqp-10.

Answer (score 0):

When you want your JMS application to send a message to a JMS topic then all you need to configure on the broker (assuming that auto-creation is disabled) is an *address* that supports multicast (as noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/jms-core-mapping.html)). You've already done that with `mySOAddress`.

Next, your application should then use the name of the *address* when it sends and consumes messages. Currently you're using the name of the queue (i.e. `mySOQueue`) when you send messages. Use this instead in your `application.properties`:

```
my.topic.name=mySOAddress
```

Your `@JmsListener` should also use the name of the address, e.g.:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "mySOAddress")
```

Then you need to configure your Spring application to use JMS topic (i.e. pub/sub) semantics rather than queue (i.e. peer-to-peer) semantics. For the `JmsTemplate` you can use `setPubSubDomain(true)`. For the `@JmsListener` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144561/how-to-listen-to-topic-using-spring-boot-jms).

Lastly, you should remove the `mySOQueue` queue.